# How to correctly use mapped types

Tags: typescript

I struggle to define a good types for my use case.
Here is what I have:
One global object that represents `Settings`

```js
const settings = {}
```

This object contains each individual menu mapped Menu title -> Menu settings.

```js
const settings = {
  menu1: {
    showOneThing: true,
    showAnotherThing: false,
  },
  menu2: {
    renderThis: true,
    renderThat: false,
  }
}
```

I am trying to come up with a function that would return different properties available in the menu, based on what menu is selected. For example

```js
const getSettings = (menuKey) => ...
const settingsForMenu1 = getSettings('menu1');
settingsForMenu1.showOneThing // intellisense and all of that
const settingsForMenu2 = getSettings('menu2');
settingsForMenu2.renderThis // property renderThis or renderThat are the only ones that should be available here
```

Now for some reason I seem to struggle with concept of generics. I think I need to use the concept of mapped types here, but I really can't figure out how.
Would anyone be able to suggest ways to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
function getSettings<
  K extends keyof typeof settings
>(key: K): (typeof settings)[K] {
  return settings[key]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUoEswHMIwLwwN4CgYYBbeMAVwEYAuPQouACxAHcB5MeAFUdTVqgAncvAA09IhGYsAgmBBRG8QTz60AZgEMANgnFEAvvpJlyAJloEGMQWQAmy1RAHCxEm-ceNNUDTr30BvhB%20OrkYMAo4DBoiADKiCjoEAA8ANIw8AAeUPaYANbwAJ4g6jBQRQAO8KVwiXwQAHwAFIVFtGkAlLTNFdW1CEgNnQDaaQC6dES2UOSCYHVDySNt48H4%20KCQsINJGABiIIIAsqaU2DHx9cnNAOSkFJS3nQDc%20LsNhydnAHRSrBxuLx0DBNuBoIs9hAvqcKGYLrEoAklhg7g9zM83h9kjDTGYfrYwA4VLwIEA)